# Restrict user access to specific paramters inside a jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I explored the role and matrix-based authorization strategies in Jenkins. I wanted to know if there are other strategies that restrict a user to a specific parameter.

For example, these are the parameters inside a Jenkins job a user can select:

- env1
- env2
- env3

Let's say that I want to provide user1 with access to job1 but only for the env1 parameter. How can I achieve this?